# Last time of a user-initiated event

Tags: java, swing

I have a fairly large swing application I'm maintaining and I have to add a timeout feature, basically where if the user hasn't interacted with the application for a certain amount of time, the application should take a specific action (shutdown for example).

Due to the fact that this application is already written it would be an insurmountable task to make every mouselistener/keyboard listener/any kind of input listener to extend/implement  a specific class/interface that would store the last time a user-initiated event happened.

Does swing already have some sort of utlity built in for something like this? What would be a good way to implement this functionality short of altering all mouse/keyboard listeners?

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: I looked for any useful fields in AWTEvent and EventObject but didn't see anything. I also did a little googling but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I did see getMostRecentEventTimeEx() in event Queue but that may apply to repainting events (which are not user-initiated) and the method is package-private.

Comment: Also looking into Toolkit.addAWTEventListener(...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// the event mask; adjust as desired
long eventMask = 
    AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK |
    AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK |
    AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK |
    AWTEvent.INPUT_METHOD_EVENT_MASK;

// install a listener for receiving global events
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(yourListenerInstance, eventMask);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks. I was on the right track with my comments above, but all the proper event masks helped as well.

Answer (score 2):

This seems relevant, I have not tried this however.

http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/

It focuses on the use of AWTEventListener, as well as hooking in to the KeyboardFocusManager.